# How does DPAPI protect MasterKey for system accounts?

Tags: windows, security, dpapi

While reading [Microsoft's documentation about DPAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995355(v%3Dmsdn.10)) I found the following text:

> DPAPI is focused on providing data protection for users. Because DPAPI
> requires a password to provide protection, the logical step is for
> DPAPI to use a user's logon password, which it does, in a way. DPAPI
> actually uses the user's logon credential. In a typical system, in
> which the user logs on with a password, the logon credential is simply
> a hash of the user's password.

That got me thinking - and what about those accounts that do not ask for passwords?

I mean the default accounts installed by Windows and IIS, such as NETWORK SERVICE, LOCAL SERVICE, LOCAL SYSTEM, ASPNET.

If I use DPAPI in a web app that runs under one of these accounts, what credentials will be used for DPAPI MasterKey?

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial (but reasonable) answer in [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22625/does-dpapi-works-if-a-user-hasnt-a-login-password):

Q:

> *Does DPAPI works if a user hasn't a login password?*

A:

> *Yes, but it's not quite as secure. DPAPI encrypts data with a master key, which is independent of the user password. When the user has a
> password, the master key is encrypted with the user's password.
> Without a password, an attacker with local access (via another user
> account) might extract the master key. However, once an attacker has
> local access to the system it's game over anyway. DPAPI is just a
> damage limitation system, really.*

Also, a comment to correct the answer:

> *Smallish correction: the master key is encrypted using the account's RSA keys, which in turn are protected using the user's password.*

So in a way it will use eg. the SYSTEM-accounts credentials to derive the encryption key but the key itself would be unprotected and quite easily achieved.

In a way the MS documentation refers this too:
*DPAPI actually uses the user's logon credential. In a typical system, in which the user logs on with a password, the logon credential is simply a hash of the user's password. In a system in which the user logs on with a smart card, however, the credential would be different. To keep matters simple, we'll use the terms user password, logon password, or just password to refer to this credential.*

But it does not explain the term 'credential'...